# My query update in mysql to my table "tabla_imagen" doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql

im doing a basic update to my table "tabla_imagen", but it doesnt work i dont know why, i was searching for my problem and i didnt found anything than helps me, my server show me this : Undefined variable: Id on the line 14 in modificar_historia.php, the rows of the table are, Id and nombre.
(like you can see i dont speak english, so if you have a doubt about mu question, please tell me, i already try on es.stackoverflow.com)

Here is my code
**modificar_historia.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registro de datos</title>
</head>

<body>
     <?php 
    include("conexion.php");




    $query = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen WHERE Id ='$Id'";
    $resultado= $conexion->query($query);
    $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
    ?>
    <center>

    <form action="modificarh.php?id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" REQUIRED name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre..." value="<?php echo $row['nombre'];?>"/><br/><br/>          
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" >  
                </form>
             </center>
    </body> 

    </html>
```

**modificarh.php**

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");

$Id = $_REQUEST['Id'];


$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

$query = "UPDATE tabla_imagen SET nombre='$nombre' WHERE Id = '$Id'";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);

if($resultado){


        echo "Si se modifico";
}
else{
    echo "No se modiifico";
}

?>
```

Comment: `Id` is not `id` case matters

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 0):

The url is using just lowercase id.

```
modificarh.php?id=
```

Change your php file to be

```
$Id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Comment: Can you do a var_dump or print_r of $_REQUEST?